# BigQuery - Collapse rows with contiguous dates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, olap

I have a table containing sales targets. They're *generally* set per month, but are loaded into the table with a row per day & market. For example, if the UK target for January is 1550, it will be loaded as 31 rows (one per day in January), each with a target of 50 (1550 / 31 days).

```
WITH targets AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-01-01' AS date, 'uk' AS market, NUMERIC '50' AS target
  UNION ALL SELECT '2018-01-02', "uk", 50
  UNION ALL SELECT '2018-01-03', "uk", 50
  # ...
  UNION ALL SELECT '2018-01-31', "uk", 50
  UNION ALL SELECT '2018-02-01', "uk", 25
  UNION ALL SELECT '2018-02-02', "uk", 25
  # ...
  UNION ALL SELECT '2018-02-27', "uk", 25
  UNION ALL SELECT '2018-02-28', "uk", 25
  UNION ALL SELECT '2018-03-01', "uk", 50
  UNION ALL SELECT '2018-03-02', "uk", 50
  UNION ALL SELECT '2018-03-03', "uk", 50
  # ...
  UNION ALL SELECT '2018-03-31', "uk", 50
)
```

I'd like to collapse this down so that each row has a `dateFrom` and `dateTo` column to reduce the effort in loading the data and the time/cost of querying it.

I've done this by grouping on market and target and aggregating max and min date and the sum of target:

```
SELECT
  MIN(date) AS dateFrom,
  MAX(date) AS dateTo,
  Market,
  target AS dailyTarget,
  SUM(target) AS target
FROM targets
GROUP BY Market, dailyTarget
ORDER BY dateFrom
```

I'd expect three rows, but there's a problem - where months with the same market & target are split by months with another target, we get overlapping rows. In the example above, both January and March have a daily target of 50 but February has a target of 25.

[image: Incorrect results]

I think the solution lies in using windowing to only group together rows where the date is adjacent to that of the previous row - but I have no idea how to implement that!

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can get the ranges using:

```
select market, min(date), max(date), target
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by market, target order by date) as seqnum_t,
             row_number() OVER (partition by market order by date) as seqnum
      from targets t
     ) t
group by market, target, (seqnum - seqnum_t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  MIN(date) AS dateFrom,
  MAX(date) AS dateTo,
  Market,
  target AS dailyTarget,
  SUM(target) AS target
FROM `project.dataset.targets`
GROUP BY Market, dailyTarget, DATE_TRUNC(date, MONTH)
ORDER BY dateFrom
```

As you can see  - you just need to add `DATE_TRUNC(date, MONTH)` to `GROUP BY`

Comment: have you tried? feel free to vote/accept if/as appropriate